# Enter Key Listener for Date is not working in linux flavours

Tags: java, swt, keylistener

Here is my full coding.I have Two class firstone MyDateTime and Second one is Employee.
i have included currently working coding of mine.For the EmployeePart class,AbstractEditorPart is our own parent class Which is extended

```
public class MyDateTime extends DateTime{

    public DateTime(Composite parent, int style) 
    { 
        super(parent, style); 
    }

    public Date getValue() 
    { 
        Date date = new Date(getYear(), getMonth(), getDay()); 
        return date; 
    }
}




public Class EmployeePart extends AbstractEditorPart(
private MyDateTime currentDate;

public void createBody(Composite parent){
currentDate=Util.createDateChooserCombo(parent, toolkit, "Date:", 2);

}

public void save(Employee input){
return null;
}
}

}
```

Comment: Try looking for keycode 10 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a little more complicated than I first thought.

One solution is to define a `TabList` for the `Composite` that contains your `Widget`s.
This way you can first define in which order you want them to be traversed.

Then add a `Listener` to each of the `Widget`s you want to traverse. This `Listener` will determine the next item in the `TabList` and force the focus on this item when either <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed.

Here is some example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Composite content = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    content.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Text first = new Text(content, SWT.BORDER);
    Text second = new Text(content, SWT.BORDER);

    content.setTabList(new Control[] {first, second});

    Listener enterListener = new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            /* Is it a traverse via Tab or Enter? */
            if(event.keyCode == SWT.CR || event.keyCode == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN || event.keyCode == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT)
            {
                /* Get source of event */
                Widget source = event.widget;

                /* Get traverse order of content composite */
                Control[] tabList = content.getTabList();

                /* Try to find current position in the tab list */
                for(int i = 0; i < tabList.length; i++)
                {
                    if(source.equals(tabList[i]))
                    {
                        /* Get the next item in the tab list */
                        Control nextControl = tabList[(i + 1) % tabList.length];

                        /* And force the focus on this item */
                        nextControl.setFocus();
                        nextControl.forceFocus();

                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    first.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, enterListener);
    second.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, enterListener);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help Baz,But its not happening.i have no problem in traversing text fields,i need to traverse java.util.date for enterkeylistener.your coding works just fine on text fields but not responding to date field.pls let me know if any other option available!!

Comment: What do you mean with _"traverse java.util.date"_?

Comment: when i press enter or tab from date field focus should be on next field.

Comment: @user2273302 `java.util.date` is not a GUI element. So what do you use to display the date?

Comment: i created a class for date in that in use java.Util.date and did some modification based on my requirements.using constructor i create UI for date.

Comment: @user2273302 You will have to post the code, because I still don't see how you display the date. Do you just use multiple `Text`s or do you use a custom `Widget`?

Comment: yes i am using custom widgets.here is my code..in that date class i have getvalue() and a constructor. those are displayed below ---- public Date getValue() { Date date = new Date(getYear(), getMonth(), getDay()); return date; }------- public DateTime(Composite parent, int style) { super(parent, style); }

Comment: @ Baz hi ..you there. help me buddy .am struck here.just tell me is there any options available to solve this issue??

Comment: @user2273302 I would have to see a complete minimal working example of your code. Based on this I can then try to get it working...